# How to tell coworker to learn and do it themselves?

Tags: conflict-aversion, coworkers, saying-no

I started using Docusign about 4 months ago. I have a coworker who needed to learn how to use Docusign as well and we attempted to connect so that I can show her how to use it.

First attempt was not successful because she said she had a last minute call to take and that we will connect later in the day but no update from her. The next day I followed up with her to see if she can connect with me so I can teach her. She pretty ignored me at this point.

She is always asking me after hours or during the day when I am busy to send some Docusign for her. She doesn’t ask she just texts me saying “send XYZ, I’ll email you the info” I decided to text her back this weekend with the log in info and step by step on sending the documents since I am not going to log in and work when I’m off. She ignored my text and decided to email me the info to send in Docusign and takes off for the next 3 days of work so I went ahead and completed the task she asked for.

About Docusign: I reached out to the supervisor to give me access and I learned it myself. Coworker asked supervisor about the docusign and supervisor told her to contact me. No paper trail since they both chatted over the phone. Teaching her wasn't a task assigned to me by my supervisor.

Mind you she’s the type of person who takes things personally and gets offended easily. I don’t want things to escalate but I don’t want to be walked on as well.

**How do I tell her to do it herself?**

Comment: Is there a manager or someone that gave you the task to teach her? Why did you do it for her after sending her how to do it herself?

Comment: She had mentioned that she will be out for the next 3 days of work so I had to send since clients and customers needs these documents. Of course if I had ignored her request, our supervisor was going to ask me to send it on her behalf while she is out

Comment: So this supervisor, did they task you with teaching her?

Comment: No. I reached out to the supervisor to give me access and I learned it myself. Coworker asked supervisor about the docusign and supervisor told her to contact me. No paper trail since they both chatted over the phone.

Comment: You're probably better off asking in Workplace SE, because I suspect a solution probably does not lie in direct confrontation, but discussing the situation with your supervisor and ask them what they'd like you to do.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I tell her to do it herself?

You don't directly tell her to do it herself.  This will just lead to a confrontation.

Whenever I have had someone ask me to do something that I had already taught them how to do and was their responsibility to do I would remind them that they already have all the information needed to complete their task.   In your case, you remind her of the instructions that you had previously sent her.  You can reply to her with something like:

> Which of the the steps in the instructions that I sent to you are you having trouble with?

This reminds her that you already sent step by step instructions on how to complete the tasks and it also reminds her that she is the one who should be following the steps to complete the task.

If she did not receive your instructions just re-send them, preferably through the company email instead of a text message.